# How create custom maven launch configuration for eclipse programatically?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am developing a custom plugin for maven, so at the final I need to create a launch configuration for maven project in eclipse. The question is, how to create a .launch configurtion file from code?

This is a sample of maven configuration, so I need to create a same file but to setup programmatically values.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<launchConfiguration type="org.eclipse.m2e.Maven2LaunchConfigurationType">
<booleanAttribute key="M2_DEBUG_OUTPUT" value="false"/>
<stringAttribute key="M2_GOALS" value=""/>
<booleanAttribute key="M2_NON_RECURSIVE" value="false"/>
<booleanAttribute key="M2_OFFLINE" value="false"/>
<stringAttribute key="M2_PROFILES" value=""/>
<listAttribute key="M2_PROPERTIES"/>
<stringAttribute key="M2_RUNTIME" value="EMBEDDED"/>
<booleanAttribute key="M2_SKIP_TESTS" value="false"/>
<intAttribute key="M2_THREADS" value="1"/>
<booleanAttribute key="M2_UPDATE_SNAPSHOTS" value="false"/>
<stringAttribute key="M2_USER_SETTINGS" value=""/>
<booleanAttribute key="M2_WORKSPACE_RESOLUTION" value="false"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.WORKING_DIRECTORY" value="${project_loc:aaa-gwt-2}"/>
</launchConfiguration>
```

Comment: You need to read up on `ILaunchConfiguration` in the Eclipse help. You will probably then have to read the m2e source to find out what the individual options mean.

Comment: For Maven a plugin ? You start the plugin via Maven and not via Eclipse...

Comment: I'm developing plugin for eclipse.

Comment: If you only need a file like that in the end, why not use normal xml facilities instead of eclipse apis?

Comment: That's what I did... I just checked if there is another ways, because like this is to much repeated code....